# Android: is it efficient to store references to Views as member variables?

Tags: android, view

If I have a view that I will be referencing with decent regularity (to change its visibility, etc...), is it more efficient to store this View as a member variable or to execute findViewById() each time I need a reference to it?

The member variable requires memory usage, while the method my take more time.  Is anyone aware of an established best practice for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is much more efficient to store the reference. The memory cost of the reference will be minimal (I don't remember the exact cost but it's in the order of 4 bytes.)

Comment: But if I store view references as members of an fragment - is they will leak when onDestroyView() occurs?

Answer (score 1):

The real concern is *where* you store the reference. Above all else, you don't want to be holding the reference when the View is no longer in use; Bad Things can result if you do.

Comment: Just to be clear, the only "where" being discussed here is "as a member of the object."  I supposed it could also be stored as a member of the class (which means declaring it as static, right?).  Here's a link explaining why that would be bad:  http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html  Any pitfalls besides making the variable static?